# Jquery Flot Chart label not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, flot

So I am learning flot charts,  but I am having a difficult time getting the label to show up or the legend when using options. Certain of the options will work (like the fill and fillColor of the lines), but not others? *Banging my head on desk*

For some reason it doesn't show up at all in jsfiddle, but it does in my web app.

```
<h1>Flot Examples</h1>
<div id="placeholder" class="placeholder" style="width:500px; height:300px; background-color:darkcyan;"  runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data, data1, dataTime, options, chart;
    var date = new Date(); //2015
    var date1 = date.setDate(date.getDate());
    var date2 = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 365); //2015
    var date3 = new Date(date.getFullYear() - 2, date.getMonth() - 5, date.getDate() - 6);

    dataTime = [
        [date1, 1],
        [date2, 3],
        [date3, 6]
    ];
    data2 = [dataTime];

    data1 = [
        [1, 4],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 9],
        [5, 7],
        [6, 6],
        [7, 2],
        [8, 1],
        [9, 3]
    ];
    data = [data1];
    options = {
        series: {
            //bars: { show: true }
            lines: {
                show: true,
                // fill: true,
                //fillColor: "#000000"
            },

        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time"
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 1
        },
        selection: {
            mode: "x"
        },
        grid: {
            show: true
        },
        //   clickable: true,
        // hoverable: true,
        shadowSize: 20,
        highlightColor: "#ffffff", //this is the color of the circle that appears
        label: {
            string: "invisible"
        },
        tooltip: true,
        legend: {
            show: true,
            labelBoxBorderColor: "#ffffff",
            position: "ne",
            margin: 10,
            backgroundColor: "#66ccff",

        }

    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //  chart1 = $.plot($('<%= placeholder.ClientID %>'), data, options);
        chart1 = $.plot($(".placeholder"), data2, options);
    });
</script>![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=zj9whJmvV5

Comment: neither the label, tooltip, or legend work, but I've only studied the label in depth as of 4-1-2015

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.js?v1.8"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.flot.mce.js?v1.8"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.flot.time.js?v1.8"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.flot.selection.js?v1.8"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.flot.categories.js?v1.8"></script>

Comment: <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend this plugin for axis labels: https://github.com/markrcote/flot-axislabels. It lets you add a label for both x and y axis really simply.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Be sure to check out all the other Flot plugins that people have made. Chances are if you're stuck somewhere, someone has made a solution for it.

Comment: where do i find those?

Comment: http://www.flotcharts.org/plugins/ and http://jumflot.jumware.com/examples/pluginsV2.html